# Mi viewcontroller no muestra los textos

Tags: objective-c

trabajo con objective c y tengo un problema muy raro... puedo pasar de un view controller a otro de forma normal, el problema es que en el segundo viewController no se pintan los labels ni los textos de los botones... alguien sabe que podria ser?

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que dejes la parte de tu código relevante al problema, sino es sumamente difícil que alguien pueda ayudarte a solucionar tu problema!

Answer (score 0):

¿Los labels no se pintan al ejecutar el programa o te sucede en la visualización del storyboard?

Pueden ser varios los motivos y necesitaríamos ver tu código para entender claramente el problema; sin embargo algo que puede ayudarte a resolverlo es hacer uso del User Interface Inspector

Solamente necesitas correr tu programa y cuando estés en el segundo ViewController  dar clic en Xcode al siguiente botón:
[image: ToolBar del Debug Area]

Una vez hecho esto, podrás revisar si realmente se están pintando tus labels, botones, etc. De esta forma puedes asegurarte que ninguna vista se esté pintando sobre tus elmentos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esta opción no te funciona, puedes revisar que tu viewController 2 realmente sea llamado desde el hilo principal, muchas veces al ejecutar un segue o presentar una vista no nos aseguramos que se esté haciendo en el hilo principal y surgen este tipo de problemas.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToSelectLogin" sender:usuario];
            });
```

Espero te sirva alguna de estas opciones!